# re: jdbc driver for MySQL cannot be found from WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts2, oracle10g

Application that uses Struts2 and Hibernate4 , MySql Server 5.1 and Apache Tomacat 7.0 ,is unable to find the jdbc driver (mySql Connector for 5.1) from the WEB-INF/lib directory.

The following error is shown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

and the same error is coming when I'm using oracle10g XE as the db and now the error comes that it cannot find the ojdbc14.jar from the WEB-INF/lib directory with the error msg:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

But when I'm explicitly specifying the driver jar in the bootstrap classloader settings in the run configurations option in eclipse, then the application is working fine.

Now I have to deploy the war onto server, I cannot use eclipse's bootstrap classloader settings in war archive ,, What is the error and what should I do now???

The hibernate.cfg.xml portion is provided for reference..

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
```

Comment: You can add the jar into build path and then export the project as jar...

Comment: Are the driver jars actually being deployed in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory? It sure doesn't sound like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ant [war task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) for building the war file and specify the lib directory where the driver is.

```
<war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${webxml.file}">
    <lib dir="${lib.dir}"/>
</war>`
```